# How to make formula in conditional formatting rule manager filldown (varies depending on cell it's applied to)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I am using conditional formatting rules manager with the formula below.If the following statement is true, then the colour of the cell is set to red and the font colour is set to yellow:

```
=IF($A$2-$A7>60,IF(B7>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

I want the B7 to change depending on the cell the formula is on. Is there anyway I can do this without using VBA/macros -- just excel formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please look into the below code, you can change the condition as per your requirement    


Dim Redcolour As Long
Dim yellowcolour As Long

        Redcolour = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        yellowcolour = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    If Condition Then


        ActiveSheet.Range("b7").Interior.Color = Redcolour
        ActiveSheet.Range("b7").Font.Color = yellowcolour

     End If
```

Comment: I want to know how to do it using excel formulas, ie. the conditional formatting rule manager

Comment: Home--> Conditional formatting--new rule--> use a formula to determine which cell format. Below are the links help to understand how to do it  .  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-cool-ways-to-use-excels-conditional-formatting-feature/

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f